# page view count increments by 2 every time wordpress page is visited in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, count

I have a simple function that should add 1 to the page views in the wp_postmeta table every time a user visits the page.  The problem is that in chrome, the number increments by two each time the page is visited.  I had initially done this on a taxonomy page and the number was actually incrementing by four on each visit.  The code I used is below and comes from http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Comment: make sure `setPostViews($postID)` is not inside a loop of any kind.

Comment: May I see your live website? Also where did you put this code snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was actually with the shortcut icon not having a path set yet.  Because no path was set, Chrome would actually try to hit the same page a second time in order to get the shortcut icon.  The following line was the problem in my header.php file:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
```

Removing this line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `getPostViews(get_the_ID());` outside the loop and `setPostViews(get_the_ID());` inside the loop to get actual count.

See code block below, I used in twentyfourteen theme:

```
<?php 
    echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); 

    // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        setPostViews(get_the_ID());

        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

    endwhile;
?>
```